# Is there a way to apply a custom matrix to glutSolid objects in FreeGLUT?

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl, glm-math, freeglut

FreeGLUT provides already some basic transformation functions such as translate, rotate and scale.

However, I need particular geometric transformations to apply to objects in a 3-dimensional space.
I'm using FreeGLUT and glm as libraries.

I'm having fun with some models already provided by FreeGLUT, such as glutSolidTorus() function.

Thanks to linear algebra I can compute matrices on which to apply vectors that correspond to points in space.
Take for example a matrix in homogeneous coordinates that projects a single point of the 3d scene on a plane. This matrix will contain values that are linear combinations of x y z that vary depending on the point being projected.

Ideally I should recalculate the matrix for each point that makes up the 3d object. But I don't have the coordinates of single vertices of this glutSolidTorus... or do I?

Is there any way to apply a custom matrix to each vertex of the FreeGLUT object? Can I have an example? Is there an easier way to achieve what I mentioned?

Comment: Loading a GLM matrix into the OpenGL matrix stack via [`glLoadMatrix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml) not working for some reason?

Comment: @genpfault
unfortunately I can't pass to the function something like `glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(myCustomMatrix))`, because the matrix contains three uninitialized variables (x, y, z) that should be the coordinates of each single vertice of the torus mesh.

Comment: @TimT your matrix **should not** contain the coordinates of each vertex. Your understanding is faulty in this regard. You build your matrix to describe the affine (or projective) transformation of the entire object, and then OpenGL multiplies each vertex by that matrix.

Comment: @genpfault That's right, that's what I normally do. I was hoping there was a way to apply matrices that express single point transformations. The one I calculated depends on a different point each time. I'll have to figure out another one. Thank you for your time!